# selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Function is not a constructor using WebDriverWait upgrading to Selenium 4.0 Java

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge, webdriverwait, selenium4

We are running selenium and java  automation project in chrome . it was running we want migrated to Micro soft Edge in that process we upgrade to Selenium 4.0 and java 1.8 edge 99.  When we run the our project we  are facing below error  edge-browser

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Function is not a constructor
```

Same code is working in chrome.

```
public void waitForLoad(long seconds) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver wd) {
            try {
                // this will tell if page is loaded
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
                String windowState = js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString();
                
                
                //String windowState = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState;");
                log.debug("wait for window[" + wd.getWindowHandle() + "] sate:" + windowState);
                log.debug("WINDOW is generated >>>>>");
                return "complete".equals(windowState);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
                log.debug("WINDOW is not loading>>>>>"+e);
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    long waitSeconds = seconds;
    if(seconds<=0){
        waitSeconds = ENV.getPageloadTimeout();
    }
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitSeconds);
    // wait for page complete
    log.debug("PageLoadState>>"+pageLoadCondition.toString());
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
```

We are facing issue in `wait.until(pageLoadCondition);` line in edge browser . Do any other way uset ExpectedConditio method

Answer (score 0):

As you migrated from lower versions of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) to ***Selenium v4.0***, the new constructor for [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) is updated as:

```
public WebDriverWait​(WebDriver driver, java.time.Duration timeout)

Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered (thrown) by default in the 'until' condition, and immediately propagate all others. You can add more to the ignore list by calling ignoring(exceptions to add).

Parameters:
driver - The WebDriver instance to pass to the expected conditions
timeout - The timeout when an expectation is called
```

and the implementation is as follows:

```
WebDriverWait wait =  new WebDriverWait(testDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(1));
```

You need to change the defination of *`pageLoadCondition`* accordingly.

---

### tl; dr

[Class WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)